# Filter data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumo

I have a pandas dataframe:

[image]

It is a large dataframe. How can i filter out all the rows with id "north_south"?

Comment: `df[~df['id'].str.startswith('north_south')]`

Answer (score 0):

The contains function under the str accessor returns the values that contain a given set of characters.

`df[df.id.str.contains('north_south')]`